# Type '' is not defined on a list

Tags: vb.net

I get the error `Type 'Address' is not defined` on all my `<lists>` and on my `GET/SET`. I have looked around but cant find why this is happening. And this only happens on this one page the other pages i used the `GET\SET` there is no errors. Anyone with a suggestion. I don't mind C# help.

My Code Sample:

```
Inherits Resource
Private Const Path As String = "listings"

Public Sub New()
    Buildings = New List(Of Building)()   'error at building 
    Features = New List(Of Feature)()     'error at Feature
    Images = New List(Of ListingImage)()  'error at ListingImage
End Sub

Public Property Address() As Address     'error at As Address
    Get
        Return m_Address
    End Get
    Set (Value As Address)                'error at As Address
        m_Address = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Address As Address             'error at As ddress
```

AND

```
Public Property Buildings() As List(Of Building) 'error at Building
        Get
            Return m_Buildings
        End Get
        Set (Value As List(Of Building) 'error at Building
            m_Buildings = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Buildings As List(Of Building)
```

Comment: `Address` is a property not a Type (Class).  Also your `Buildings` *et al* are defined as a List array. get rid of the trailing parens, if that is not what you want.  Address should probably be `As String` you cant define it as itself

Comment: @Plutonix, Thanks but how do I fix this? I had C# code and tried to convert it to vb that's why I m not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a property as a type of itself:

```
Public Property Address() As Address     'error at As Address
```

The trailing parens here define it as an indexed property, which is also probably not intended.

It should probably be:

```
Public Property Address As String
```

If there *is* an address type somewhere, escape it, or use a different name:

```
Public Property [Address] As Address
```

---

You cant use the same variable over and over to mean differnt things.  For building you have:

```
 Buildings = New List(Of Building)() 
 ' and
 Public Property Buildings() As List(Of Building)
```

`Buildings` can **either** be a List or a Property, not both.  And the one is likely not really a List Array.  This is probably what you meant:

```
Private m_Buildings As List(Of Building)    ' a list (not array) of Type Building
Public Property Buildings As List(Of Building) 
    Get
        Return m_Buildings
    End Get
    Set (Value As List(Of Building)
        m_Buildings = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

There must be a class somewhere called `Building` which might be what the compiler is complaining about

Comment: I have edit my original post about building, would that make a difference or should I still remove ().

Comment: one thing at a time.  what is Address?  are there many addresses and you will do something like `thisAddr = foo.Address(5)` or is it just a string?  THe building property suffers from the same thing, but one thing at a time.

Comment: I am using a api for real estate company. so yes there will be many addresses. C#: `Buildings = new List<Building>();` with `public List<Building> Buildings { get; set; }`

Comment: but addresses are strings like `"123 Happy Street", no?  Wouldn't Address be a property on the Building type?  Do you have a Building class somewhere? see Edit for more syntax fixes

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `As Address` to whatever type you need to represent (probably `String` for an address). Like Plutonix said, if `Address` actually is a type, use brackets. Otherwise, a property is not a type.

About the errors on the types in the `List`, you need to declare the types `Public` if they will be used in any public method. So, make sure you place `Public` before the `Class` keyword defining your own types. Example:

```
Public Class Building
 ' members
End Class
```

Also, unless you want an array of `List`s, which I'm guessing you don't, remove the `()` after the list constructors.